# 'Xcode cannot find protocol declaration of "UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning"'

Tags: delegates, xcode6, nsobject

I created a vanilla Xcode (v6.2) project (Project A) that throws the error:

> 'Xcode cannot find protocol declaration of
>   "UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning"'

Here's the code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface WTF : NSObject <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>

@end
```

Weird thing is, I have a example project that I downloaded (Project B) that I can put the exact above code in and it will recognize UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning protocol without a problem:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface WTF : NSObject <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>

@end
```

The most obvious differences I notice between the two projects are that the second downloaded project has the frameworks listed in the explorer, but the project I created with Xcode 6.2 does not. Upon further reading I found that new versions of Xcode eliminate the need to manually hook up frameworks, so I'm not sure if it's relevant.

So with Project A throwing an error on something that Project B does not, I started a new project (Project C) in Xcode (Single View Application) and pasted in:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface WTF : NSObject <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>

@end
```

And get the same error:

> 'Xcode cannot find protocol declaration of
>   "UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning"'

Restarted Xcode and Mac and the error persists.

WTF is happening here?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Ugh. Needed to import

```
UIKit/UIKit.h
```

3 hours.

Comment: Thanks for saving everyone else the time. Took one for the team.

Comment: Question is why the UIKit import is needed in new projects and older projects work with Foundation import only? This is happening all over in my new project.

Comment: @shelll before, Xcode by default add the precompiled header to the project (.pch) and it contains UIKit import, and because this file is implicitly included at the start if every source file, we did not have to import UIKit.